# Maximum call stack size exceeded on foreach async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I use a forEach loop in [traverse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/traverse)

```
   await traverse(json).forEach(async function (value) {
       for(var i=0 i<10; i++)={
           var result=  await someFunction(i);
           var result2= doSomething(result);
       }
       var r = result2;
   }
```

as soon as I set the inner function to `async` I get an `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. What can I do?

Comment: It sounds like `someFunction` calls this code block, ie it indirectly calls itself and you have an endless cycle . Therefore at some point the call stack is too big

Comment: BTW `forEach` won't wait for `someFunction()` to get resolved.

Comment: None of the methods `traverse` offers understand `Promise`s or cares about them.

Comment: We can't help without more information (what does `someFunction` do, for instance?). But using `async` functions as `forEach` callbacks is an antipattern if you don't A) want them to run in paralle, and B) use `try`/`catch` to handle rejections (since `forEach` doesn't do anything with the promise). More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: I added some info, I have to await a result, therefore I need to use await?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [@T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) say

forEach doesn't care about async usage (doesn't wait for it). You can take a look at [traverse-async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/traverse-async).

I think this package can be more flexible for this scenario.

```js
let queue = traverse(object, function(node, next) {
  someAsyncOperation(node)
  .then(next)
  .catch(err =>{
    queue.break();
  });
}, function() {
  console.log('Done!');
});
```

Comment: Don't use a callback-based library for promises though. This won't handle errors correctly.

Comment: This can be done with try catch. That's not a big deal

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include this, it *is* an important thing that's too easily forgotten

Comment: This way it should be fine ?